# Как разделы header и footer вынести отдельные файлы, то есть каждый блок в отдельный файл?

Tags: html, веб-программирование

Создал проект в галпе. Теперь возник вопрос, как настроить структуру файлов. Понимаю, что такие блоки как header и footer нужно выносить отдельно, чтобы потом в потребности изменить один файл, а он изменился на всех страницах. Посоветуйте статьи, видеоуроки, где это разбирается. Буду благод

Comment: В зависимости от сервера это делается по разному. Есть http-расширение позволяюще делать `<!--include` под апач. Есть php, есть asp и aspx. В каждой технологии это делается по-разному. Уточните вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этих целей я использую rigger:

gulpfile.js:

```
var rigger = require('gulp-rigger');

// Задача html
gulp.task('html', function() {
  gulp.src(path.watch.html)
    .pipe(rigger())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.html));
});
```

где `path.watch.html` - путь до папки с файлами html, а `path.build.html` - путь куда вы собираете проект.

Теперь в index.html (например):

```
//= templates/head.html
//= templates/header.html

<div class="content" id="root">
 //= pages/main.html
</div>

//= templates/footer.html
```

rigger собирает вам index.html вставляя в него код из указанных файлов